# Linux network OS boot from grub bootloader ISO

Tags: linux, linux-networking, operating-system, grub2

I have an idea to boot the system with network files for automated installation of OS
I have created an ISO with gub-mkrescure with just a grub inside it, so when it boots the grub menu will appear only and it will load files but getting a server not found error when loading it.

Here is the grub file:

```
cat > isofiles/boot/grub/grub.cfg << EOF
set timeout=5
insmod http
set root=‘(http-server-ip)’menuentry “Load ISO 1 from HTTP” {
linux http://(http-server-ip)/path/to/vmlinuz boot=live config
initrd http://(http-server-ip)/path/to/initrd.img
}menuentry “Load ISO 2 from HTTP” {
linux http://(http-server-ip)/path/to/vmlinuz boot=live config
initrd http://(http-server-ip)/path/to/initrd.img
}
EOF
```

Comment: ever heard of PXE?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Network) the syntax for network boot is `(protocol[,server])`. [here is an example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228452/can-grub-load-a-kernel-from-http)

Comment: I can see some progress over this problem, it seems I am not getting the "server unreachable error". I am confused about whether Grub is able to access the network or not. I tried the command net_dhcp, getting the error message "no network card found"